# Apple In-App Purchase receipt version 3 (suddenly appearing instead of version 2)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

The receipt validation in my app started breaking recently. Apparently, in the last 2-3 weeks Apple has changed the version number of the In-App Purchase receipt from `2` to `3`.

When examining the signature struct:

```objc
struct signature_blob {
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t signature[128];
    uint32_t cert_len;
    uint8_t certificate[];
} *signature_blob_ptr = (struct signature_blob *)signature_bytes;
```

…where `signature_bytes` is the Base64-decoded value of the signature string from the JSON blob from the [`transactionReceipt`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/transactionReceipt) (deprecated as of iOS 7) the [`SKPaymentTransaction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKPaymentTransaction) object.

…I had hard-coded a check for `version == 2`. Now I am seeing a value of `3`.

After a couple years in the App Store, in the last 2-3 weeks our app began getting user reports of new purchases and “Restore” purchases failing to activate our app’s content. So I assume this is a recent change on Apple’s part.

Can anyone confirm Apple made a change? Provide further details? Perhaps point me to documentation about this new version of purchase receipts?

Comment: Hey, when this list is correct the last changes were 3 month ago. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentRequest_Class/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008255-CH99-SW1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Apple introduced the version 3 signature some time in early April. I haven't found any documentation or change log, but this is understandable since `transactionReceipt` is deprecated.

The difference in version 3 is the signature length, it's now 256 bits instead of 128 and it's signed with the latest [Apple Inc. Root Certificate](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/).

Comment: Do you know if there are any other versions out there, other than 2 and 3?